# JavaScript - split groups of strings between ( ) and put them inside two separated inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this line:

> first (word1-word2-word3) second (any1-any2-any3)

Lets say I have a **textarea and two inputs** (**input1** and **input2**).

When I paste the line above inside the **textarea**, and by using JavaScript, I want:

> word1-word2-word3

to go to the first input (**input1**) and for the other part;

> any1-any2-any3

to go to the second input (**input2**).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression and take the two matching groups.

```js
function split(v) {
    var m = v.match(/^.*\((.*)\).*\((.*)\)$/);
    document.getElementById('input1').value = m[1];
    document.getElementById('input2').value = m[2];
}
```

```html
<textarea onchange="split(this.value)"></textarea><br>
<input type="text" id="input1"><br>
<input type="text" id="input2">
```